# Criar loop de dados recebidos pelo post e inserir no mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, post

bom dia. estou tentando fazer um sistema para pedido de compras.
gostaria de saber como faço para receber os valores do $_POST e enviar para um banco. O problema é que essas informações do $_POST são dinâmicas. Gostaria de criar uma especia de arrary e inserir essas informações em uma tabela do mysql.

Exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Adicionar o botao de incluir itens:**

```js
$('#addmore').click(function(){

                // Get last id 
                var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
                var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

                // New index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

                // Create row with input elements
                var html = "<tr class='tr_input'>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' name='username_"+index+"' placeholder='Informe o produto'></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='id_' id='id_"+index+"' name='id_"+index+"' readonly></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='name' id='name_"+index+"' name='name_"+index+"' ></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_"+index+"' name='salary_"+index+"' onKeyUp='moeda(this);'  ></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='remove(this)'>Excluir</button></td></center></tr>";

                // Append data
                $('tbody').append(html);

            });
```

**TR para inserção de dados:**

```html
<tr class='tr_input'>

                    <td><center><input type='text' class='username' id='username_1' name="username_1" placeholder='Informe o produto'></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='id' id='id_1' name="id_1" readonly></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='name' id='name_1'  name="name_1" required></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_1' name="salary_1" onKeyUp="moeda(this);" required></center></td>

                <td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="remove(this)">Excluir</button></center></td>

            </tr>
```

**form para enviar via post:**

```html
<form method="post" action="cad-novo-pdc.php">
```

Answer (score -1):

`$_POST` é um array que contém uma série de pares chave/valor com o nome do campo e seu valor, passados por `POST` no request `HTTP`. Então, é só percorrer o mesmo com o `foreach` (como se faz num array normal). Segue um exemplo abaixo, onde se printa a lista de chaves/valores:

```
<?php
$query_string = "";
if ($_POST) {
  $kv = array();
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $kv[] = "$key=$value";
  }
  $query_string = join("&", $kv);
}
else {
  $query_string = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
}
echo $query_string;
?>
```

Retirado de: https://odesenvolvedor.com.br/percorrendo-todos-os-registros-do-post_1208.html

Answer (score -1):

Opa amigo, tudo bom ? Cara para fazer isso é até que bem simples. Você só precisar usar um elemento do seu HTML como refêrencia de " tamanho " para que o PHP percorrar todos os dados. Em segundo passo, em seu HTML você precisa transformar seus elementos em uma forma de "Array", para isso é só colocar `[]` em frente de cada um no `name`destes. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

Seu HTML:

```
<tr class='tr_input'>

                    <td><center><input type='text' class='username' id='username_1' name="username_1[]" placeholder='Informe o produto'></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='id' id='id_1' name="id_1[]" readonly></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='name' id='name_1'  name="name_1[]" required></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_1' name="salary_1[]" onKeyUp="moeda(this);" required></center></td>

                <td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="remove(this)">Excluir</button></center></td>

            </tr>
```

PHP para inserção dos dados:

```
$id_insert = $connect->insert_id;
$qtd_itens = sizeof($_POST['username_1']);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $qtd_itens; $i++) {

        $produto = $_POST['username_1'][$i];
        $codigo = $_POST['id_1'][$i];
        $qtd = $_POST['name_1'][$i];
        $preco = $_POST['salary_1'][$i];

        $query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('{$id_insert}', '{$produto}', '{$codigo}', '{$qtd}', '{$preco}';)";

        if(!$connect->query($query) === true)
            die("Erro na inserção dos dados <br>" . $connect->error);
}
```

Com este código, o PHP verifica a quantidade de INPUT's existentes com o nome passado e com isso ele sabe a quantidade de vezes que fará o loop pegando valor de cada outro input passado no `for`. A variavel `[$i]` faz esse trabalho de separar cada valor de cada input para sua devida linha, e com isso, cada linha de maneira inteira é inserida em sua DB. Eu coloquei esse `$id_insert` no código, mas não sei se você trabalha com uma PK em sua BD onde contém o ID do "Pedido", caso não tenha, pode excluí-la.

Comment: Amigo, descobri o porque ele só está pegando a primeira linha. Em seu JS, você está fazendo da maneira errada a adição dos produtos. Você está mudando também o valor do ID dos itens. Você deve fazer essa adição usando como parâmetro os ```name``` em forma de Array como te citei. Como você está mudando o ID dos elementos, ele só está pegando a primeira linha mesmo. Tire a parte de mudar os ID's que você verá que vai dar certo.

Comment: Esqueci de dizer que isso aplica também para o ```name```, no mesmo você não precisa colocar um index diferente no JS. Seria melhor você fazer um ```clone()``` de sua tabela e depois dar um ```apend()``` do que fazer da maneira atual. Deixe o name como Array ao invés de ir adicionando index's ao mesmo, pois é através do name que é enviado os dados ao Banco. Por isso, se você fazer o clone(), funciona duma maneira muito melhor, pois o mesmo já será clonado como Array.